# Using an expression in Groovy HQL update

Tags: groovy, sql-update, hql

I'm trying to set a column in one table based on one of two possible columns from another one.  [Since HQL updates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct) do not support joins, I'm trying to work around and use an `OR` in the `set` statement, however, I'm not able to find much [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct) on it.

Similar queries appear to work in some flavors of SQL, but I cannot seem to get it to work in Groovy's HQL:

```
String queryString = """
    update Foo foo
    set foo.myValue = (
        (foo.fooType = :typeBar AND :barFlag = true) OR
        (foo.fooType = :typeBaz AND :bazFlag = true)
    )"""

Map args = [
    typeBar: Type.BAR,//String
    typeBaz: Type.BAZ,//String
    barFlag: bar,//Boolean
    bazFlag: baz,//Boolean
]

Foo.executeUpdate(queryString, args)
```

The exception I'm getting is:

`org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: OR near line ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't use expressions in HQL `update` statements.  Had to break it off into two queries instead, e.g.:

```
String queryString = """
    update Foo foo
    set foo.myValue = :bar
    where foo.fooType = :type"""

Map args = [
    type: Type.BAR,//String
    flag: bar,//Boolean
]

Foo.executeUpdate(queryString, args)
```

then something similar for type `baz`.